# Как распаковать .rar архив с паролем ? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rar, winrar, archive

Пробовал с помощью библиотеки **rarfile**, смог распаковать .rar архив без пароля, но при распаковке архива с паролем, столкнулся с такой ошибкой `'test.rar' is encrypted with WZ_AES encryption and requires a password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
password = 'pass'
file.extractall(pwd=password)
```

Comment: Что такое `file`?

Comment: Я не знаю что это было, но сегодня это заработало, вчера тоже самое делал, и ничего не работало. Видимо я вчера установил нужные компоненты, но не перезагрузил пк, поэтому была ошибка

Comment: @Robot Если вы копировали текст с какого-либо сайта, то могла кодировка вставленного текста просто не восприниматься вашей IDE, у меня в PyCharm иногда бывает такое

Comment: @tonysdev, код сам писал, я уже нашёл решение моей проблемы, ошибка была в коде

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать интерфейс командной строки WinRAR

```
import os

path_to_rar = r'"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"'
archname = r'c:\test\test.rar'
outfolder = r'c:\test\unpack_folder\\'
password = '1212'

cmdline = fr'{path_to_rar} x -p{password} {archname} {outfolder}'
os.system(cmdline)
```